# Как создать сертификат TLS КРИПТОПРО через linux, для доступа к ftp?

Tags: linux, tls, криптопро

Необходимо создать TLS сертификат через cripto pro под linux. Создание сертификата и его использование необходимо в частности для доступа по ftp. На форумах и документации criptopro https://www.cryptopro.ru/ не найдено ничего что могло бы помочь. Есть инструкция от Equifax под установку сертификата для Windows. Программа называется "КриптоАРМ 5.4".  Там полностью описана установка по пунктам:

1. [Создание запроса на получение сертификата](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrK7T.png)
2. [Установка сертификата шаг 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkyLL.png), [Установка сертификата шаг 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxSCN.png)

Как реализовать генерацию TLS сертификата не под Windows, а под Linux? Для последующих запросов и доступа на ftp

Comment: чем же вас не устраивает `openssl`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Если можно через openssl, то будет отлично. Я слаб в этой теме. На ваш взгляд его возможностей будет достаточно и нужно копать в его сторону?

Comment: криптопро ставится для сертифицирования в фсб и тп... для бизнеса достаточно опенссл. там нужно просто прогрузить плагин и далее как с обычным опенссл генерируется всё. Если выпускать под линукс на криптопро - то там нужна отдельная программа за много денег